# How to convert my time data from character to time in R?

Tags: r, filter, type-conversion, data-conversion, datetime-conversion

I have a time column in a data set, and it is of character type. For example, "12:00". I want to change the type of data to filter it. (Like filter(time > 12:00) let's say.)

I have used chron::strptime but unsuccessful in getting what I want.

I have done it with mutate(hours= hm(Time)). This converted my data to "20H 59M 0S". I don't know if it is okey to analyse data and filter like " filter(hours> "12H 0M 0S" "?  Is this a correct way?

Comment: You can use durations (as in lubridate::hm) as long as your time has a strict ordering. For example, it won't work if you have a time of 23:59 which you want to be recognised as being two minutes earlier than 00:01, but that is always going to be a problem if you have times without dates, unless you are always strictly comparing times on the same day, or comparing times abstractly.

Comment: All I want is to know which kind of products purchased more in specific times like below:

Comment: when <- mydata %>% 
  select(Time,Quantity,Payment,Product.line) %>% 
  mutate(hours=hm(Time)) %>% 
  filter(hours > "20H 30M 0S") %>% 
  arrange(desc(hours)) %>% 
  group_by(Product.line) %>% 
  summarise(totalquantity=sum(Quantity))

Comment: Yes, you may use `filter(hours > "20:30")` directly on character vectors. It will resort to an alphabetical comparison, that will reliably order times formatted as `HH:MM` on a 24 hours basis. (Don't compare e.g. `"12:00"` to `"20H 30M 0S"` though, since they're formatted differently)

Comment: Exactly what was the problem with your attempt at using chron?  What specifically did you do?  `chron::times` usually works well.  It certainly supported comparisons.`